# Introducing Spring Batch fails Dao-Test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch in a Spring Boot application as below. Spring Batch and the application seem to work fine with that configuration.

However, with that configuration for a simple Dao-Test (not for Spring Batch) I get the following exception. Without the Spring Batch configuration the test is running fine. **Update**: The problem appears if I configure to use an own JobRepository with a transaction manager (below in class MyBatchConfigurer).

I tried to provide another transaction manager for Spring Batch but I am running from exception to exception.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3505)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1427)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1423)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy165.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy165.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.dao.GenericDao.save(GenericDao.java:60)
    at com.foo.dao.GenericDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$71a0996b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 37 more
```

Test Setup

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.foo.entity")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestPropertySource("/mytest.properties")
@Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:/testdata.sql")
public class MyTest {

    @Inject
    private OrderDao sut;

    @Test
    public void test_findByAnotherFieldId() {
    final Order order = // build an order ...

    sut.save(order);

    final Order result = sut.findByAnotherFieldId("valueOfOtherField");

    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(order);
  }

}
```

Spring Batch Job configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(OracleDatabaseConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = MyBatchConfigurer.class)
public class BatchJobConfig {

    // Injects...

    @Qualifier("analyseOrdersJob")
    @Bean
    public Job analyseOrdersJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("analyseOrdersJob").start(analyseOrdersStep()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step analyseOrdersStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("analyseOrdersStep").<Order, String>chunk(4)
            .reader(orderItemReader) //
            .processor(orderItemProcessor) //
            .writer(orderItemWriter) //
            .build();
    }
}
```

Spring Batch configuration

```
@Component
public class MyBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
        try {
          return extractJobRepository();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
          throw new BatchConfigurationException(e);
        }
    }

    private JobRepository extractJobRepository() throws Exception {
        final JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }
}
```

ItemReader

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class OrderItemReader implements ItemReader<Order> {

  @Inject
  private OrderDao orderdao;

  private int nextOrderIndex;
  private List<Order> orders;

  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct() {
    orders = orderdao.findAll();
  }

  @Override
  public Order read() {
    if (nextOrderIndex < orders.size()) {
      final Order order = orders.get(nextOrderIndex);
      nextOrderIndex++;
      return order;
    }

    return null;
  }

}
```

ItemWriter and ItemProcessor are similarly configured.

Comment: You didn't share the most important part of the story: the `getTransactionManager()` method. Can you share its code please? Which transaction manager do you use? According to the exception, it looks like you are using JPA, so you would need to use a `JpaTransactionManager` in your Spring Batch config, because by default, a `DataSourceTransactionManager` will be used.

Comment: The transaction manager is coming from `org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer` which - as you stated - is using a `DataSourceTransactionManager` since `MyBatchConfigurer` extends `DefaultBatchConfigurer`. Doing that I followed the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#txConfigForJobRepository).

Using an example like from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-spring-batch) works when using a `ResourcelessTransactionManager`. Both tests and application work then.

Comment: However, using the code above and just doing a `@Override
  public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
  }` does not work

Comment: Just overriding the `getTransactionManager` was not possible before version 4.1.0.M3 (See https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2294). You can use the latest RC (4.1.0.RC1) to be able to only override the getter in your `BatchConfigurer`.

Comment: Ah. Thanks very much!